# How to reduce the complexity of nested loops to generate all ip-addresses

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is what i came up in my code which is taking so much time.

**Algo**

```
loop i in 0 -> 255
    loop j in 0 -> 255
        loop k in 0 -> 255
            loop l in 0 -> 255
                output string(i.j.k.l) //ip-address
```

Can you please tell a way to reduce its complexity from O(n^4) to something less? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's a lot of ip addresses.  It will take a long time to list a lot of things.  Why do you need to list them all?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Teepeemm I need to record json response of ip-api.com/json/*ip-address*. Some private ip ranges are being exempted but thats in if statement for output which i didn't bother to mention because that wouldn't be of any help.

Comment: So you're wanting to get an ajax response for almost every ip address?  That will take too long, and the api will stop answering you.  You need to rethink your approach.

Comment: You could reduce (to 1) the number of loops, but if you count to 4 bn, you cannot do less than 4 bn! Anyway you can remove the private segments (10.*, 192.168, 172.16~31..) but that doesn't count much (~0.25%). Or split among multi-cores

Answer (score 1):

You cannot produce `O(f(n))` output in time less than `O(f(n))`.  If you want this to run faster, you need to produce less output.

You know, IP addresses tend to be physically close to nearby IP addresses...

Answer (score 1):

First off, I don't know what problem you're actually trying to solve, but it's unlikely that it requires you to look up every possible IP address. If you gave us more context (i.e. what is the larger problem that you think requires this solution?), perhaps we can give you some more realistic alternatives. The information below explains why you can't improve on your algorithm if you really want to look up all possible addresses.

There are 4 billion or so possible IP addresses. Some are in private ranges that you can't query, and other combinations might be invalid. Unless you do some frontend filtering, you'll have to check all 4 billion. Even with filtering, though, you'll be checking a very large fraction of the entire possible range.

Your code is only O(n^4) if n is in the range 0..255. That's an odd way to look at things. Another way to look at it is that n is 2^32 (i.e. 4 billion and change), and you need to check every one. Then it's O(n). And you can easily go through them all in a single loop:

```
uint ip = 0;
do
{
    // convert the integer to an IP address by extracting the individual bytes.
    if (ip not in private address range)
    {
        // do the lookup
    }
    ++ip;
} while (ip != 0);
```

Let me stress, though, that aside from the up front filtering, this isn't any more or less efficient than your original algorithm.

You're better off doing the private IP range filtering up front (before doing the lookup). That way you don't waste time looking for something you know can't be there.

By the way, a good average time for DNS lookup is on the order of 60 ms if you have a DNS server on your local network. Assuming you could maintain that, the time to look up every possible IP address will be:

```
60 ms * 2^32 addresses = 257,698,037.76 seconds
```

That works out to a little more than 8 years.

Added later: According to the link Ami Tavory posted in his answer ([Reserved IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses)), there are about 600 million reserved addresses. If you filter those out, you knock about 15% off the time requirement. You could do it in only 7 years!)

You need to approach your problem differently.

Comment: nice explanation by the way

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the question narrowly, in terms of "how to speed up these 4 nested loops", you cannot improve the complexity, by definition.

Undoubtedly, though, you need this for doing something with each IP address, and some of them are irrelevant. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses), for example, is a list of reserved IP addresses.

You probably can come up with something different, or more specific, for your case.

If you can somehow code these restrictions into the loops, you might reduce the complexity. E.g.:

```
 for i0 in 0 - > 255 if not restriction0(i0):
     for i1 in 0 -> 255 if not restricion1(i0, i1):
         for i2 in 0 - > 255 if not restriction2(i0, i1, i2:
                 for i3 in 0 -> 255 if not restricion3(i0, i1, i2, i3):
                     do something
```